# Concourse integration with Gerrit

Tags: gerrit, concourse

I am trying to integrate Concourse with Gerrit and facing some issue "latest version of resource not found"
Below is the yml file used.  Can anyone help me in letting me know what could be the issue here.
The url mentioned is dummy.
The project name is "sup/component/cyc/cyc-test/test-code"

Trying to clone the master branch data.
Please let me know if any additional information is required.

---

resources:

- name: test-code

  type: gerrit

  source:

  branch: master

  uri: https://user1@gerrit.testteam.com/a/sup/component/cyc/cyc-test/

  username: user1

  password:

jobs:

- name: test-gerrit
  plan:

  - get: test-code
  - task: build

    config:

    platform: linux

    image_resource:

    ```
    type: docker-image

    source:

      repository: maven

      tag: 3.6.3-jdk-11
    ```

    inputs:

    - name: test-code
      outputs:
    - name: the-artifact
      params:
      branch: master
      run:
      path: bash
      args:
    - -exec
    - |
      cd test-code/
      ls -ls .
      pwd

Integrate Concourse with Gerrit and facing some issue "latest version of resource not found"